# How to search video in Vimeo?

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

For searching videos in Vimeo I use [this](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/channels/%7Bchannel_id%7D/videos) query:

```
    const path = pagingPath ?
        `https://api.vimeo.com${pagingPath}`
        : `https://api.vimeo.com/channels/${channel}/videos?per_page=20&query=${filter}&fields=link,name,pictures.sizes.link,status,release_time,width,height`;
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        path,
        {
            data: `app_id=${appConfig.VIMEO_APP_ID}&token=${appConfig.VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${new Buffer(`${appConfig.VIMEO_APP_ID}:${appConfig.VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET}`).toString('base64')}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        },
    );
```

You can see that I want to search for videos on my channel. And this query works fine if my `filter` contains only full words. ('How to make something #1'). If I send request with 'How to mak' I'll get nothing.

[This](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos) endpoint works fine with all variants of the query. But I can't send my `channel`.

So how can I search a video in Vimeo in my channel?

Comment: Is the channel public on vimeo.com and are the individual videos in that channel also public? Private videos CAN exist within channels, however private videos are not indexed and will not return in search queries.

Comment: @TommyPenner It is public channel. And I can get all the videos that I want, if I send request with `query = 'How to make'` or `query = 'How to'`. But I will not get anything if I send with `query = 'How to ma'`.